# TypeScript Type for function arguments not erroring?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to define what arguments must be passed to a function in React with Typescript:

```
type IncrementDecrementFunctionArgs = {
  id: number;
  amount: string;
  foo: string;
};

export const dummyProps = {
  increment: function({ id, amount }: IncrementDecrementFunctionArgs) {
    console.log("increment ", id, " by amount: ", amount);
  }
}
```

Props are spread into component:

```
<Component {...dummyProps} />
```

Component calls function:

```
  const handleClick = (val: incrementDecrement) => {
    if (val === incrementDecrement.increment) {
      increment({ id, amount });
    } else {
      decrement({ id, amount });
    }
  };
```

I can't work out why this isn't erroring. `foo` does not exist. `id` is a string and `amount` is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function you've implemented can, in-fact, accept `foo` as a property of the object parameter.

The following is valid with your function:

```
props.increment({id: 1, amount: 2, foo: 3}); // no runtime errors.
```

Ignored properties are allowed in TypeScript, because it is valid to call with parameters that are being ignored by the function.

Comment: Hey! I know this is can be rude, but I been looking for someone to help me with writing better answers. Because I have been trying to find you in chat rooms for over two weeks, I just wanted to ask you what improvements I can do in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507019/delete-a-file-just-after-it-is-shared-in-android/57507331#57507331, or if it is great to tell me. If you think this comment should be removed I would happily remove it. Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Please check it out.